# Three.js cubeCamera envmap not working

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Hey i got a 2 problems with cubecamera with the three.js plugin.

Everytime when i setup a cubecamera

```
cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 100000, 256, 128 );
//cubeCamera.renderTarget.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
cubeCamera.doubleSided = true;
scene.add( cubeCamera );

var cubeTarget = cubeCamera.renderTarget;
```

as soon as i enter `scene.add( cubeCamera );` the script crashes and outputs:
“Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined”

I searched everything tried everything.
Now i managed to make it work only not how it should work.

I never added the cubeCamera but in my render function i did the following:

```
cubeCamera.position.z = 100;
cubeCamera.position.x = 200;
cubeCamera.position.y = 0;
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
```

And i got the following output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeXB9.png

So what am i doing wrong? and why can't i write the line `scene.add( cubeCamera );` ??

Thanks in advance,
Bram

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Jason a well working reflection on the sphere, because it now shows the monkey about 10 times, and that should be one time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the answer!

Just had to update the three.js script from r47 to r49..

Now it works, had to change some other things like the collada loader ;)

So for next time, ALWAYS check if i am up to date (A).